# How to find similar pie charts?

Tags: algorithms

What algorithms should I research to sort pie charts by similarity?

The real-world problem I'm working with is a collection of race data for a few dozen cities — each race listed as percent of the city's population.

I'm interested in selecting a single city and finding other cities with similar racial proportions.

Comment: Forget about the chart; that's just a visualization. Instead represent each city as a distribution over races, and sort them by [KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence). Note that this method is very sensitive to small entries on the comparison side, so use accurate non-zero estimates. Otherwise use the [Hellinger distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance) to be less sensitive. Welcome to the site!